# Is dynamic condition block with aws_lb_listener_rule possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a load balancer listener with terraform as such

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
  listener_arn = data.aws_lb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecs_group.arn
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = length(var.route_path_patterns) > 0 ? [] : [1]
    path_pattern {
      values = var.route_path_patterns
    }
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = length(var.route_host_patterns) > 0 ? [] : [1]
    host_header {
      values = var.route_host_patterns
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I do so I am getting 3 errors:

1x "Insufficient condition blocks" - for the whole aws_lb_listener_rule (as if there we no conditions at all)

2x "Unsupported block type" - for each of the host_header and path_pattern blocks, as if the dynamic declaration weren't there at all.

I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 2):

When you use dynamic blocks, you need to use `content` block:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "static" {
  listener_arn = data.aws_lb_listener.https.arn
  priority     = 100

  action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.ecs_group.arn
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = length(var.route_path_patterns) > 0 ? [] : [1]
    content { 
        path_pattern {
        values = var.route_path_patterns
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "condition" {
    for_each = length(var.route_host_patterns) > 0 ? [] : [1]
    content {
        host_header {
        values = var.route_host_patterns
      }
    }
  }
}
```